# MySQL query issue. SUM TOP 3 per type and top 1 per group by reference

Tags: mysql, sql

I have been trying to write an SQL query to select the top 3 per type per user and sum together with the top 1 of another type per user. I apologise if it sounds complex but I can't think of a better way to describe it. The query must be compatible with MySQL 5.x.

I have been trying to adapt a previous query with no joy. It has currently been setup to return the first 5 rows per type per user and treat every other row as a value of 1. I've tried to change some clauses to produce the desired effect with no joy.

```
SELECT
 wsf_ref
,sum(wsf_value) as total
from (select
*,
( select count(*)
 from individual u
 where
   t.wsf_ref = u.wsf_ref and
   t.type = u.type and
   t.wsf_value <= u.wsf_value
) as number
from individual t) t
where (number <= 3 and type <> 'blue' and status = 'Approved' and wsf_progress IN ('Day 1', 'Day 2', 'Day 3'))
or (number = 1 and type = 'blue' and status = 'Approved' and wsf_progress IN ('Day 1', 'Day 2', 'Day 3'))
group by wsf_ref
order by total desc
```

### Example Data

```
id     wsf_ref   status     type       wsf_progress   wsf_value
1      001       Approved       orange     Day 1          5
2      001       Approved       orange     Day 1          10  *
3      001       Approved       orange     Day 1          20  *
4      001       Approved       orange     Day 1          10  *
5      001       Approved       blue       Day 1          10 
6      001       Approved       blue       Day 1          25  * 
7      002       Approved       red        Day 1          10
8      002       Approved       red        Day 1          20  *
9      002       Approved       red        Day 1          30  *
10     002       Approved       red        Day 1          20  *
11     002       Approved       orange     Day 1          10
12     002       Approved       orange     Day 1          20  *
13     002       Approved       orange     Day 1          15  *
14     002       Approved       orange     Day 1          40  *
15     002       Approved       blue       Day 1          20
16     002       Approved       blue       Day 1          35
17     002       Approved       blue       Day 1          50  *

* denotes rows to be summed in the example.
```

For this example the type of 'blue' is the TOP 1 only. The 'status and 'progress' are not really relevant in this example but I would like them included as WHERE criteria.

```
Expected Results
----------------------
wsf_ref     total
002         195
001         65

Current Results
----------------------
wsf_ref     total
002         120
001         45
```

It looks like it's only selecting the top 1 for each type and ignoring the number <= 3 clause.

Comment: why blue is the top1? please explain the logic

Comment: That doesnt help me @Strawberry

Comment: Sorry, I need  (top 3 wsf_values per type where type != blue) + (top 1 wsf_value per type where type = blue) grouped by wsf_ref.

Comment: Can you edit the question accordingly?

Comment: if you said top 3 why 002 has 7 rows mark for sum ?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza the types are different. Top 3 per type.

Comment: what about ties? still top 3?

Comment: the total would still be the same for ties.

Comment: I mean if you have 4 rows with 10, then top 3 still 30 or 40 ?

Comment: The total would then be 30

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**SQL DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/36b5fc/17)

First with user variables you need create a rn to get the top 3 for each `type` and `ref`

```
SELECT t.*, @rn := if(  @ref = `wsf_ref`,
                       if ( @type = `type`, 
                             @rn + 1,
                             if( @type := `type`, 1, 1)                     
                           ),
                       if ( (@ref := `wsf_ref`) or (@type := `type`), 1, 1)
                    ) as rn,
            @type,
            @ref
FROM t
CROSS JOIN ( SELECT @rn := 0, @type := '', @ref := '') as var
ORDER BY `wsf_ref`, `type`, `wsf_value` DESC ;
```

**Partial Result**

```
| id | wsf_ref |   status |   type | wsf_progress | wsf_value | rn |  @type | @ref |
|----|---------|----------|--------|--------------|-----------|----|--------|------|
|  6 |       1 | Approved |   blue |        Day 1 |        25 |  1 |   blue |    1 |
|  5 |       1 | Approved |   blue |        Day 1 |        10 |  2 |   blue |    1 |
|  3 |       1 | Approved | orange |        Day 1 |        20 |  1 | orange |    1 |
|  2 |       1 | Approved | orange |        Day 1 |        10 |  2 | orange |    1 |
|  4 |       1 | Approved | orange |        Day 1 |        10 |  3 | orange |    1 |
|  1 |       1 | Approved | orange |        Day 1 |         5 |  4 | orange |    1 |
| 17 |       2 | Approved |   blue |        Day 1 |        50 |  1 |   blue |    2 |
| 16 |       2 | Approved |   blue |        Day 1 |        35 |  2 |   blue |    2 |
| 15 |       2 | Approved |   blue |        Day 1 |        20 |  3 |   blue |    2 |
| 14 |       2 | Approved | orange |        Day 1 |        40 |  1 | orange |    2 |
| 12 |       2 | Approved | orange |        Day 1 |        20 |  2 | orange |    2 |
| 13 |       2 | Approved | orange |        Day 1 |        15 |  3 | orange |    2 |
| 11 |       2 | Approved | orange |        Day 1 |        10 |  4 | orange |    2 |
|  9 |       2 | Approved |    red |        Day 1 |        30 |  1 |    red |    2 |
| 10 |       2 | Approved |    red |        Day 1 |        20 |  2 |    red |    2 |
|  8 |       2 | Approved |    red |        Day 1 |        20 |  3 |    red |    2 |
|  7 |       2 | Approved |    red |        Day 1 |        10 |  4 |    red |    2 |
```

Then use a conditional `SUM`

```
SELECT wsf_ref, SUM( CASE WHEN type = 'blue' and rn = 1 
                          THEN `wsf_value`
                          WHEN type <> 'blue' and rn in (1,2,3)
                          THEN `wsf_value`
                          ELSE 0
                     END
                   ) as sum_total
FROM ( 
        SELECT t.*, @rn := if(  @ref = `wsf_ref`,
                               if ( @type = `type`, 
                                     @rn + 1,
                                     if( @type := `type`, 1, 1)                     
                                   ),
                               if ( (@ref := `wsf_ref`) and (@type := `type`), 1, 1)
                            ) as rn,
                    @type,
                    @ref
        FROM t
        CROSS JOIN ( SELECT @rn := 0, @type := '', @ref := '') as var
        ORDER BY `wsf_ref`, `type`, `wsf_value` DESC   
     ) t
GROUP BY `wsf_ref
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| wsf_ref | sum_total |
|---------|-----------|
|       1 |        65 |
|       2 |       195 |
```

**EDIT:**

After asking around I got with a simpler version:

[What boolean value return assign integer or string to a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56590229/what-boolean-value-return-assign-integer-or-string-to-a-variable)

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6fee1c6/6)**

```
SELECT t.*,
       (@rn := if(@tr = CONCAT_WS(':', wsf_ref, type),
                  @rn + 1,
                  if(@tr := CONCAT_WS(':', wsf_ref, type), 1, 1
                    )                     
                 )
       ) as rn
FROM (SELECT t.*
      FROM t 
      ORDER BY `wsf_ref`, `type`, `wsf_value` DESC
     ) t CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT @rn := 0, @tr := '') params;
```

Comment: Nearly there but it seems to be summing duplicates as well

Comment: Actually, it's adding an extra row for the first type. So for orange the rn is 1, 1, 2 ,3 instead of 1,2,3,4. The @type for that row is blank too.Only for the first row so it's very close.

Comment: what you mean an extra row? I got your desire result

Comment: I’ll post the outcome tonight. The same code as you’ve supplied, works fine in dB-fiddle but when actioned on my server via PHP it’s adding an extra row. It’s selecting the top 3 for red, top 1 for blue which is correct. However orange has four rows. There is two orange rn=1 but the @type is blank for one and orange in the other. Baffling!

Comment: well dont add another layer to the test using PHP, test it direct on mysql. I really dont see how would be two orange with rn=1.  Will wait for your reply. Try to change the data in the sqlfiddle so I can reproduce it.

Comment: I've found the issue but not sure how to rectify. It's the WSF_REF adding the extra row. If i change the ref to a number it returns the correct results. Example http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bac344/1 . It should be 150 as result.

Comment: Change `AND` for `OR` on `if ( (@ref := wsf_ref) OR (@type := type), 1, 1)`

Comment: Thanks, works well. I've been struggling with the final part of my project which is to add the wsf_progress into the query. So the final result would be the SUM of top 3 (top 1 for blue) wsf_values, per type, per wsf_progress, per ref. So top of Day 1, Day 2 for each day etc. Can you help in here or is it a new question? I'm using the original method and not the simplified version.

Comment: I dont understand what you just said. Maybe create a new question and explain better and linked here so I check it later.  remember accept the answer here

Comment: Will accept. Sorry my brain is fried. It’s that same as we have now but adding wsf_progress as a group.

Comment: Just before I ask a new question. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e763593/4 removing the Day 1 from the schema returns a different result when only querying Day 2. should be 55 both times surely.

Comment: the problem is you calculate the rn with all the rows so you already assign rn and lost them when filter by 'Day 2' what you need to do is add the day filter on the inner query first http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e763593/85

Comment: btw you also need add the `else 0` on the `CASE` statement. to make sure you dont try to add `NULL`

Comment: Added the ELSE 0 again, not sure how it dropped off. Thanks for your answer. I had actually figured it out by the time you replied but it works now. Thanks again.