# What boolean value return assign integer or string to a variable

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, user-variables

Im using user variables to emulate

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY `wsf_ref`, `type` ORDER BY `wsf_value` DESC)
```

Pay attention to the `@type` variable. I set it to `a` to make the issue clear but at first was an empty string.

```
CROSS JOIN ( SELECT @rn := 0, @type := 'a', @ref := '') as var
```

[**SQL DEMO #1**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/369265/1)

```
CREATE TABLE t (
  `id` INTEGER,
  `wsf_ref` INTEGER,
  `status` VARCHAR(8),
  `type` VARCHAR(6),
  `wsf_progress` VARCHAR(5),
  `wsf_value` INTEGER
);

SELECT t.*, @rn := if(  @ref = `wsf_ref`,
                       if ( @type = `type`, 
                             @rn + 1,
                             if( @type := `type`, 1, 1)                     
                           ),
                       if ( (@ref := `wsf_ref`) and (@type := `type`), 1, 1)
                    ) as rn,
            @type,
            @ref
FROM t
CROSS JOIN ( SELECT @rn := 0, @type := 'a', @ref := '') as var
ORDER BY `wsf_ref`, `type`, `wsf_value` DESC;
```

You can see first row enter the last condition and set both variable correct:

**OUTPUT**

```
| id | wsf_ref |   status |   type | wsf_progress | wsf_value | rn |  @type | @ref |
|----|---------|----------|--------|--------------|-----------|----|--------|------|
|  6 |       1 | Approved |   blue |        Day 1 |        25 |  1 |   blue |    1 |
|  5 |       1 | Approved |   blue |        Day 1 |        10 |  2 |   blue |    1 |
|  3 |       1 | Approved | orange |        Day 1 |        20 |  1 | orange |    1 |
```

Buf if `wsf_ref` is a `VARCHAR` i got a different result

[**SQL DEMO #2**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6fee1c6/1)

```
CREATE TABLE t (
  `id` INTEGER,
  `wsf_ref` VARCHAR(255),
  `status` VARCHAR(255),
  `type` VARCHAR(255),
  `wsf_progress` VARCHAR(5),
  `wsf_value` INTEGER
);
```

Here you can see first row the variable `@type` isnt set and still have `a`

**OUTPUT**

```
| id |  wsf_ref |   status |   type | wsf_progress | wsf_value | rn |  @type |     @ref |
|----|----------|----------|--------|--------------|-----------|----|--------|----------|
|  3 | WSF19-01 | Approved |  Perch |        Day 2 |        20 |  1 |      a | WSF19-01 |
|  4 | WSF19-01 | Approved |  Perch |        Day 2 |        10 |  1 |  Perch | WSF19-01 |
```

After some debuging I found the problem is with the last assignment

```
if ( (@ref := `wsf_ref`) and (@type := `type`), 1, 1)
```

On first case when `wsf_ref` is integer the assignment evaluate to true and then the second condition is also checked. On the second case when `wsf_ref` is string the result is false and the second condition is ignored.

I change the condition to:

```
if ( (@ref := `wsf_ref`) OR (@type := `type`), 1, 1)
```

So even if the first condition is false still try to evaluate the second condition and now both query are working ok.

**So why assign `@ref` a number get a different boolean than assign a string?**

Comment: Reading & assigning a variable in the same select statement is undefined in MySQL--see the manual re variables & assignment. Certain expressions involving CASE work for certain implemenations but that isn't guaranteed behaviour. (I don't have a link.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expression is:

```
if ( (@ref := `wsf_ref`) and (@type := `type`), 1, 1)
```

MySQL does not necessarily evaluate both conditions.  It only needs to evaluate the "second" one if the "first" evaluates to true.  (I put "first" and "second" in quotes because the order of evaluation is not determined, but the idea is the same regardless.)

When these are strings, the result of `@ref := wsf_rf` is a string.  The string is converted to a boolean, via a number.  The value is `0` -- which is false -- unless the string happens to start with  digit.

Hence, both conditions are not evaluated and the second is not assigned.

I would write this as:

```
SELECT t.*,
       (@rn := if(@tr = CONCAT_WS(':', wsf_ref, type),
                  @rn + 1,
                  if(@tr := CONCAT_WS(':', wsf_ref, type), 1, 1
                    )                     
                 )
       ) as rn
FROM (SELECT t.*
      FROM t 
      ORDER BY `wsf_ref`, `type`, `wsf_value` DESC
     ) t CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT @rn := 0, @tr := '') params;
```

I moved the `ORDER BY` to a subquery because more recent versions of MySQL don't handle `ORDER BY` and variables very well.

Comment: I see. I imagine was something like that, but in my mind was if is something not 0 then should be true. Didnt know string become 0. And that `CONCAT` trick is great, took me lot of work handle those nested `IF` thanks